# Sed on big multiple files fails (37kB each)

Tags: unix, sed

I've tried this on multiple small files, everything works fine.
But when testing sed on multiple files with size 37kB each, only one file completely processed while other files become horrible.

Below is the codes Im running:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's/<title>/sblmtitle\n<title>/g' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '1,/sblmtitle/d' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's/<div class="entry entry-cont"/\n<div class="entry entry-cont"/g' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i -n '/<div class="entry entry-cont"/q;p' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's/<\/title>/<\/title>\nslpstitle/g' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's/<h1><a href="/sblmurl\n<link>/g' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '/slpstitle/,/sblmurl/d' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '/<link>/s/">/<\/link>\nslpsurl/g' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's/<div id="down" class="entry entry-cont">/sblmkonten\n<div id="down" class="entry entry-cont">\ndeldlmkonten/g' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '/slpsurl/,/sblmkonten/d' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '/deldlmkonten/,/<iframe/d' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's/<div id="down" class="entry entry-cont">/<description>/g' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '$s/$/<\/description>/' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i 's%​%%g' &&
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i '/^$/d'
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: What do you mean "other files become horrible"?

Comment: The penultimate line with "`xargs sed -i 's%​%%g'`" globally replaces the empty string with the empty string - which is not as fast an operation as all that, and seems a little pointless.

Comment: @John Zwinck, it not cleanly processed. Something it should remove is still there

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler, Thats not empty, but its some unknown character replaced with empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have say that this is pretty inefficient. You are finding same set og `*.html` files every time and running some sed command. Why don't you combine multiple sed commands into 1 big sed command like:

```
sed -e 's/<title>/sblmtitle\n<title>/g' -e '1,/sblmtitle/d' ....
```

And do all processing in 1 single find command like this:

```
find ./ -type f -name '*.html' | xargs sed -i.bak ....
```

Comment: Even better than a ton of `-e` options on a command line would be to use the oft-forgotten feature of sed that reads the commands from a file.  Then the whole pile of substitutions can be written in a saner way.

Comment: @John: I agree with your basic point.  However, the scripts would have to modified slightly (I now observe) because the first two work in tandem:  "`xargs sed -i 's/<title>/sblmtitle\n<title>/g'`" and "`xargs sed -i '1,/sblmtitle/d'`" can't be directly combined in a single script.  That said, I believe that the required result can be achieved, probably with "`-e '/<title>/p' -e '1,/<title>/d'`" which prints the title before deleting the line.

Comment: Agreed, in this case it is definitely better to place multiple sed commands in a separate file. I will add an Edit section.